# Propel ORM returns error, while executing INSERT statement

Tags: php, propel

I have this `schema.xml` config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="manager" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="users" phpName="Users">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />  
        <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true" />
        <column name="desc" type="longvarchar" required="true" />
    </table>
</database>
```

And i have this php code

```
$user = new Users();
$user->setName('admin');
$user->setDesc('');
$user->save();
```

And i get this error

```
Unable to execute INSERT statement [INSERT INTO users (id, name, desc) VALUES (:p0, :p1, :p2)]
```

I use latest version of slim framework and latest version of Propel ORM. I write script 2 moutn ago and it will be works, but now i install it and it doesnt working, because i cant execute any Insert statements. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see between the config and your code, what happens if you did `$user->setDesc('a non-blank value')`?

Comment: @sjagr if setDesc non blank value, i get the same error.

Comment: @PatrickBurns have you tried running the raw/failing statement directly?

There might also be a few possible issue at play here.  `desc` is a MySQL reserved word for `describe`ing the table, in which case you should try changing `desc` to its long form `description`

Another possibility is that the query as is currently, the column names aren't being escaped with a backtick

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `desc` is being intepreted as a syntax error because it is a reserved word, maybe try rename `desc` to something alse, e.g. `Description`.